# Claymore autostart on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server

I have installed recently Ubuntu in my miner rig, but I have to start claymore manually, I tried to configure it to autostart, but the program didn't show me anything so I was not sure if the script is working.

At this moment when I run it manually, I have to open a terminal, search the folder with the program, and run the script. In the terminal, I can see how does work the program.

Is there a way to set up to autostart with the same behavior? I mean, that system opens a terminal and shows me the program running? How can I do that?

I'm windows user, very noob in linux

Comment: I followed this tuto https://steemit.com/tutorial/@jeramyroberts/ethereum-amd-gpu-mining-tutorial-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Comment: The parte where I have to put this command  sudo nano /etc/rc.localv, it shows me a blank document, not clear if something is wrong

Comment: Yes, the tuto is very well done, but I can't be sure if the process is running or not, if I could check out I could say everything is ok.

Comment: This may help you. It opens the miner in a terminal so you can watch it. https://ricksfix.fs87.com.au/2020/12/20/crypto-miner-autostart-script-on-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts/